# Delete [Reverse Backspace] Button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-button

I have built a delete button, just like in Windows, which removes the string on the right hand side of the cursor(one by one). [Instead of the mainstream Backspace which removes the left side.]

However, when the right side is null, the `onClickListener` should display a toast message.

But the app crashes.

This is what I made :

```
package com.reverse.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView.BufferType;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public Toast t;
    Editable a, b, d, f, a1;
    String e;
    public int c, d1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText ed;

        Button dlt;

        dlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        dlt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = ed.getEditableText();

                b = a;
                c = ed.getSelectionStart();

                boolean daj = b.toString().isEmpty();
            if (!daj) {

                    String a22 = b.toString().substring(0, c);
                    int strChar = a11.length();
                    String strcut = a11.substring(1, strChar);
                    e = a22.concat(strcut);

                    ed.setText(e, BufferType.EDITABLE);
                    b = ed.getEditableText();
                    ed.setSelection(c);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cool",
                            t.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Logcat :

```
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=1; regionLength=-1
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18795)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
06-05 17:03:41.394: E/AndroidRuntime(967):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If the right hand side of the text in editText, String a11, is `null or ""` then why does it enter the `if` loop? Why doesn't it continue to the `else` statement?

Comment: `b.toString().substring(c);` is returning `-1` and thats why you are getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: you can get the last character as follows: `char lastCharacter = text.charAt(text.length() - 1);`..check if that helps you...

Comment: I'm asking why did it enter the if loop if a11 is null.

Comment: It's a reverse backspace. Not a backspace. I don't need the last character.

Comment: what are you trying to get with this code??? `String a11 = b.toString().substring(c);`

Comment: change `if (a11 != null) {` to `if (b.toString().matches(""){` and check if that helps.. and comment out `String a11 = b.toString().substring(c);`..Have a try..

Comment: To get the right hand side of the cursor and put it into another string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:length=0;regionStart=1;regionLength=-1
```

Check This Out the *Same thing is happening with your* `a11`

```
    String a="";<---Value in a11
    System.out.println(a==null);--->False
    System.out.println(a.length());---->0
    System.out.println(a.substring(1,0));--->String index out of range: -1
```

---

So Check your `a11` like this.

```
if(a11!=null && !a11.trim().equals(""))
```

Comment: `trim()` will remove extra preceding or trailing spaces.

Comment: It works. :D
I've finally made a Reverse backspace aka delete button for android. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are hardcoding the starting index as `1` in following piece of code. Your string length should be more than 1 if you want to access its index 1. Check

```
String strcut = a11.substring(1, strChar);
```

Your string length should be at least 2 if you want your above code "Not to crash".

Comment: The function enters it only if a11 is not null. The problem is, if a11 is null, then why does the app crash? It just skip the if statement and go to else.

Comment: Your app will crash if a11 is not null but an empty string or string with length 1

Comment: BUT WHY DID IT ENTER THE IF LOOP?

Comment: Try this: String str = ""; if(str != null) {}
Do you think this will not enter inside?
What you need is if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())

Comment: Are you trying to cite the difference between "" and null?

Comment: Sorry. But I checked with both and it still crashes.

Comment: Well, the check should be that the string length is more than 1 because you are accessing its index 1.

Comment: If there is one character, what do you think it's length would be?

Comment: 1, and it will still go inside and crash because by providing the index 1, you are trying to access the second element.

Comment: Alright. What do I replace the condition statement with?

Comment: I edited my question. Now, if a11 is null, it shows toast. But if it is not, and there is no text on the right hand side of the cursor, it crashes.